# Why upstart service does not stop when sys.exit is called by Python

Tags: python, linux, upstart, system-services

I set up a Python application as a Linux service using Upstart script.

```
description "AAE client app"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

env PATH=/home/ec2-user/aae_client/env/bin
env PROGRAM_NAME="aae"
env USERNAME="ec2-user"

# Main script to be run
script
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Ready to run..." >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log

    export HOME="/home/ec2-user"
    echo $$ > /var/run/$PROGRAM_NAME.pid

    cd /home/ec2-user/aae_client
    exec python -m app.run >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log 2>&1
end script
```

I want to stop the service when `sys.exit` is called inside the python code due to some exception being caught.

```
if not config_path:
    logger.error('Environment variable AAE_CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH is not set')
    sys.exit()
```

As it turns out, `sys.exit` did terminate the current process, but somehow the service keeps getting respawned. If I run `status [service]` again and again, it would show the service running every time with a new PID.

Is there a way to kill the service completely within the code?

Comment: You can remove the `respawn` directive if you don't want the service to automatically respawn.

Comment: @DanielPryden Instead of respawning right away, is there a way to wait for a certain period of time and respawn again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it respawns the process whenever it exits because that's what you told it to do. That's what the `respawn` directive is for.

If you want to respawn but not immediately, you can add a post-stop delay.

The ["Delay Respawn of a Job" section of the Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#delay-respawn-of-a-job) gives this example:

```
respawn
exec mydaemon
post-stop exec sleep 10
```

You can modify the sleep to whatever is appropriate for your service.